# Intellij Scala classpath not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to use `json4s` but I keep getting the error below when I compile. I thought the library would have the class internally. I am using `json4s-ast_2.11-4.0.0-M1.jar`, `json4s-core_2.12.3.5.3.jar` and `json4s-jackson_2.9.1-3.0.0.jar`.

```
Error:(64, 25) Symbol 'type org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'type org.json4s.JValue'.
Make sure that type JValue is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.json4s.JsonAST.
```

Imports:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s._
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ast" % "4.0.0-M1"
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.5.3"
```

Comment: The question is internally inconsistent. The build.sbt you show would pull only `_2.12` libraries (because you use `%%`, as you should), but at the beginning of the question you claim you are using a mixture of `_2.11`, `_2.12`, and `_2.9.1` libraries. These can't both be true.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use libraries compiled for different versions of scala in other versions. You need to fix the versioning of your JSON4s. Look at:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html#Using+Cross-Built+Libraries

Comment: I am new to all this. Can you be specific on which library? Do you mean all library must be the same version? I checked on mvnrepository.com and those 3 packages should be compatible with Scala 2.12. Please help!

Comment: Nor can you mix and match json4s versions (3.0.0, 3.5.3, 4.0.0-M1). Pick _one_ Scala version (`%%` does that for you) and _one_ json4s version. According to https://github.com/json4s/json4s it should be sufficient to add a single dependency on `json4s-jackson`; this will automatically pull in `json4s-core` and `json4s-ast` without you needing to explicitly add them.

Comment: That makes sense. When I remove those dependencies in .sbt file, it still complains the JValue not in class path tho. :(